# Need help to submit a variable from HTML

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I am new to HTML so please bear with me. I want to submit a "variable" or request parameter  called "user" as a http request. A server side code will pick up this 
username and process it. I tried some code and it gives me a blank ouutput:

**HTML -**

```
<form method="POST" action = jstl.jsp>
<input type="text" name="user" value="enter username"/>
<button type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

**JSP or server side code -**

```
<c:if test="${user eq 'admin'}">
   You are now a admin.<br>
</c:if>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Well, what did you try? Can you paste a code snippet? 
I hope you tried AJAX, right?

Comment: @Cheeku - All the code is in my question. Is there something else you required ? I don't know AJAX and won't be learning that now.

Comment: @Cheeku I don't know how ajax can be involved to solve this problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, I thought he was already using AJAX, and my comment was confirming that hypothesis. It can't be.

That's why I asked for a code snippet. I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is good, but in the JSP code you need to precede your user variable with "param".

Like So:

```
<c:if test="${param.user eq 'admin'}">
   You are now a admin.<br>
</c:if>
```

You may also benefit from looking at this more comprehensive example:

[JSP Form Post Example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/CheckParameterValueandOutputErrorMessage.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I really need all the help i can get.

Comment: Provide code, not just mention the code that is in an external link.

Comment: Fix is - `${param.user eq 'admin'}`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev it would be better if you accept an answer that can help future readers as well as you.

Comment: Answer edited to benefit all mankind as Luiggi Mendoza has requested.